# get only last array vlaue from ArrayList android

Tags: android, arraylist, iteration

I am using `GridView` with camera to show images (maximum 4 images)
i need all the captured images path in `ArrayList` ,

The problem is when the loop iterates , it give me previous array value along with latest array

**Eg:**

```
iteration 1 : [imagepath1]

iteration 2 : [imagepath1,imagepath2]

iteration 3 : [imagepath1,imagepath2,imagepath3]
```

I need only the latest iterated value

```
i.e :  [imagepath1,imagepath2,imagepath3]

// ArrayList<String> imageList;

private List<String> RetriveCapturedImagePath() {
        List<String> tFileList = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(GridViewDemo_ImagePath);
        if (f.exists()) {
            File[] files = f.listFiles();
            Arrays.sort(files);

            //Log.e("f.listFiles();", "files "+files);


            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                File file = files[i];
                if (file.isDirectory())
                    continue;
                tFileList.add(file.getPath());
                Log.e("file.getPath()", "karfile " + file.getPath());

                imageList.add(file.getPath());                          
                Log.e("imageList RetriveCapturedImagePath", "karimageList" + imageList);    

            }

        }
        return tFileList;
    }
```

Comment: Something like this imageList.get(imageList.size()-1)); ?

Comment: where to include ? ... pls have a look at imageList.add(file.getPath());

Comment: where ever you need the last paths

Comment: yes I modified the comment to use **imageList** because it is member of the class

Comment: imageList.add(tFileList.get(tFileList.size()-1));.. still same result ... gives me all iterated values

Comment: You lost me now mister. Why do you even have that imageList if you only want the latest?

Comment: thanks bro ... it helped me .. using two ArrayList made me go mad..